# R Max If function?

Tags: r

Is there any way to do a max if function in R? I am trying to clean up data by summarizing it and only pulling out information where it occurs the most instance. In Excel I would use MAX(IF for this. Is there any way to do the same thing in R?

Comment: Could you give a minimal example for that with the desired output?!

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output.

Comment: I would try the following scheme: `ifelse(test=what_you_want_to_check, yes=max(some_data),no=something_else_happening)`

Answer (score 3):

[As I understand it](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2011/07/27/finding-min-if-or-max-if-in-excel/), `MAX(IF(C2:C8=C11, D2:D8))` in Excel would basically take the maximum value of the D cells for the condition `C2:C8=C11` holds true. This is a one-liner in R:

```
# Some data
x <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
y <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60)

# Maximum y value where x equals 2
max(y[x == 2])
# [1] 40
```

This code returns the maximum `y` value assuming the corresponding `x` value is equal to 2.